# How can I read and bind data from this JSON to a Select dropdown in Angular 2+

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api

This is what my JSON looks like:

```
{
    "Stations": {
        "44": {
            "NAME": "Station 1",
            "BRANCH_CD": "3",
            "BRANCH": "Bay Branch"
        },
        "137": {
            "NAME": "Station 2",            
            "BRANCH_CD": "5",
            "BRANCH": "Beach Branch"        
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if its possible to extract the "NAME" and "BRANCH" values from each "Station" and bind them to separate Select inputs [dropdowns]

I am using Angular 4.
Here is what I have:

```
 this.apiService.getStations().subscribe(data => {
      this.stationList = data.Stations;
     }, err => {
      this.errorFetchingStations = err;
      console.log("Error getting list of stations " + err);
    })
```

`this.stationList` gives me an object of this format in the console:

```
{44:{NAME: "Name of station", BRANCH: "Name of branch"}}
{137:{NAME: "Name of station", BRANCH: "Name of branch"}}
```

and so on.

If I try to bind the stationList to my select like this, I get an error

**ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed**

```
    <select class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let station of stationList" [value]="station.NAME">{{station.NAME}}</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having key value pair to the object instead ngFor expects an array so you should use the below code

```
 this.apiService.getStations().subscribe(data => {
      this.stationList = Object.values(data.Stations); // returns an array
     }, err => {
      this.errorFetchingStations = err;
      console.log("Error getting list of stations " + err);
    })
```

Comment: Wow. That was it. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: Quick follow up, the way the data is set up is that the BRANCH is repeated for multiple "Stations". for example, Station 1, 9 and 10 will have BRANCH = "Branch 1". Short of de-duplicating the array, is there a way to get a distinct list of BRANCHes?

Answer (score 1):

you should transform the stationList to array and you can use the Object.values(data.Stations), as the below.

```
this.apiService.getStations().subscribe(data => {
  var stations = data.Stations;
  this.stationList = Object.values(stations);
}, err => {
  this.errorFetchingStations = err;
  console.log("Error getting list of stations " + err);
})
```